# Interpret a `Sem (x ': r) a` into a `Sem (y ': r) b`?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, effect-systems, haskell-polysemy

I'm trying to put together the machinery to write something like secret-sharing ([*e.g.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing#t_=_n)) using algebraic effects. More specifically I'd like to be able to write the *protocol* in terms of the actions of each individual party, and then handle that effect-space into a simulation of some number of actors all talking to each other.

I want to use algebraic effects because I think it's cool, and I think it will help with some of the subsequent analysis. [Polysemy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polysemy) seems like a good choice of library.

As an example, consider the simple case of three parties trying to get the sum of their secret inputs. We might write something like

```hs
import Polysemy (Member, Members, Sem, makeSem)
import Polysemy.Random (Random, randomR)

data Communication3 s m a where
  Message :: (s, s) -> Communication3 s m (s, s)  -- Pass a message, and get peers' messages.
  Secret :: Communication3 s m s                  -- Input one's own secret values.
  Reveal :: s -> Communication3 s m (s, s)        -- Share a value with all peers, and get theirs.

makeSem ''Communication3  -- Uses template haskell to generate:
-- message :: Member (Communication3 s) r => (s, s) -> Sem r (s, s)
-- secret  :: Member (Communication3 s) r =>           Sem r s
-- reveal  :: Member (Communication3 s) r => s ->      Sem r (s, s)


--------- The "application" code: --------

modulus = 1013 :: Int
modulo = (`mod` modulus)
randomM :: Member Random r => Sem r Int
randomM = randomR (0, modulus - 1)

sumOfSecrets :: Members [(Communication3 Int), Random] r =>
                Sem r Int
sumOfSecrets = do
  myInput <- secret
  noiseB <- randomM
  noiseC <- randomM
  (shareInB, shareInC) <- message (noiseB, noiseC)
  let shareInA = modulo (myInput - noiseB - noiseC)
  let shareResultA = modulo (shareInA + shareInB + shareInC)
  (shareResultB, shareResultC) <- reveal shareResultA
  return $ modulo (shareResultA + shareResultB + shareResultC)
```

(Whether or not the above is any good would be good to know, but not the question here. It *does* typecheck, once you get Stack to compile polysemy-zoo.)

**How would I write a handler for the `Communication3` effect?**

If we imagined we were trying to implement this as an internet protocol, then the "executable" would look a lot like the code we've written; messages would get handled into whatever process for sending and receiving data over the wire.
**But** I also (in fact, *primarily*) want to be able to simulate the three parties locally. That means, roughly speaking that I need to write a handler/interpreter/runner like

```hs
runCommunication3 :: Sem ((Communication3 a) ': r) b -> Sem r (b, b, b)
```

representing running the whole thing three times (mostly) in parallel.

Clearly this is possible to do; the `State` handlers do it. But I haven't been able to find any documentation of how. Where should I be looking? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you can try to first translate your effect to some `State`/`Reader` effect.